# why first code give error and second does not?

Tags: c, output

This is the first code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(int,int);

int main()
{
  int p=23,f=24;
  test(&p,&f); 
  printf("%d %d\n",p,f);
  return 0;  
}

void test(int q,int g)
{
  q=q+q;  
  g=g+g;
}
```

This code generates TYPE MISMATCH ERROR maybe due to the fact that I have passed address of variable as argument during function calling and the formal parameters are not pointers.

This is the second code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{    
  int p=23,f=24,q,g;
  q=&p;
  g=&f;
  printf("%d %d\n",q,g);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of second code is

1638220 1638228

In this code, `q` and `g` are not pointers. So why are they giving correct output, not the error?

Comment: You are passing pointers to a function that is asking for two integers.

Comment: `q = &p;` and `g = &f;` are wrong. What's your intention with assigning a pointer value to a non-pointer variable? What's a "correct output"? Why do you think it correct? What would be an erroneous output?

Comment: @H2CO3 How does the second example compile? Shouldn't he get "Type int* can't be assigned to int" or something like that?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yeah, it definitely should be the case.

Comment: Since he's saying "the output of the second code"..

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you disable any warning?

Comment: With XCode the first code generates only a warning, but compiles and run correctly: `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'int *' to parameter of type 'int'; remove &` - result: 23 24

Comment: I am using Borland v.5.0

Comment: the second code prints the correct addresses of p and f
where as first code gives error

Comment: the program is tested

Answer (score 3):

*Note:*
Your comment: *"The second code prints the correct addresses of p and f where as first code gives error"* is wrong on various levels.
You claim your `printf` statement prints the memory addresses of the variables? Wrong, it does no such thing. Can't. Impossible. Not going to happen.
To print the memory addresses of variables, a `printf` statement should look like this:

```
printf("p @ %p\nf @ %p\n", (void *) &p, (void *) &f);//one of few cases where you SHOULD cast
```

You're printing just a number:

```
printf("%d %d", p, f);
```

Those *are not the same thing*. Just take a look at the example at the bottom of this answer, but read the bit in the middle, too

Well, you declared `q` and `g` as ints, and assigned them the memory addresses of `p` and `f`. It's undefined behaviour (ie the standard doesn't determine what to do with this, so it may vary depending on the compiler, WCS: your application crashes). In your case, I'd say this happens:
Basically, a memory address looks something like this:

```
0x213ABC
```

A hexadecimal value, which can be interpreted as a number, so there's nothing stopping your from assigning it to a `char`, or `size_t` or whatever.
*HOWEVER*, if you compile your code with `-Wall`, you should get a warning about the *implicit* conversion from type `int *` to `int`. Aside from that, you're *"safe"*. Mind your: the program's output will be unpredictable and therefore rather pointless.

The first snippet contains a bigger problem: you're passing a value to a function that simply *does not exist*! The `test` function *cannot handle what you're passing*, because its prototype shows it expects 2 ints, not 2 pointers

```
test(&p,&f);
//to:
test((int) &p,(int) &f);
```

However, it *does* compile, [as you can see here](http://codepad.org/irfddDXY), however the results are unpredictable (undefined behaviour).

When calling `test(&p, &f)` you are calling a function that should look like this:

```
void test(int *, int *)
```

However, this signature/prototype is nowhere to be found, so the compiler can't continue. Casting the memory addresses to ints changes all that, and lets the compiler know that the function looks like `void test (int, int)`, and that function *does* exist, hence it compiles.

Think of it like this:

> You: What's your phone-number?
>   Me: abc
>   you: That's not a phone number
>   Me: I meant 1-11-111 (number keys for text messages, those were the days)

That's what you're doing here:

```
test(&p, &f);
//compiler: can't find function test(int *, int *)
//you: I expect you to call test(int, int), and implicitly cast the pointers to ints
```

That's not how C works.

*Note:*
As pointed out to me in the coments: Assigning/casting *pointer* to *int* is undefined behaviour (ie: the result of these actions are not defined by the standard)

---

The example program that prints pointers, and unsigned long and ints as they should be printed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int p = 2, f = 4, q;
    q = (int) &f;
    printf("p @ %p\nf @ %p\n", (void *) &p, (void *) &f);
    //int is too small for 64bit address, use unsigned long here
    printf("%d != %ul != %p\n", q, &f, (void *) &f);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I ran it through [this codepad](http://codepad.org/vOHnggNv), I got the following output:

```
p @ 0xbf70e1d8
f @ 0xbf70e1d4
-1083121196 != 3211846100l != 0xbf70e1d4
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean its behavior is undefined?

Comment: @haccks Exactly, it is -- since it contains a constraint violation.

Comment: @H2CO3: Added that to my answer, and clarified a bit better why `test(&p, &f)` can't ever be compiled

Comment: in first code I am storing a address in non pointer variable and in the second also I am storing a address in a non pointer variable....
then why first code give error and second does not

Comment: @user2607801: No in the first snippet, you're calling a function and passing it 2 addresses, so you're calling a function that doesn't exist, and should look like `test(int *, int *)`, in the second version, you're assigning a memory address to a non-pointer. The behaviour is undefined, but an apparently, the mem-addresses are implicitly cast (and truncated) to ints

Comment: @haccks: Updated a bit more, focussing on undefined behaviour, and why it's bad

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem There's no such thing as an "implicit cast", casts are explicit by definition. It turns out OP's compiler does an implicit conversion, but that's non-conforming -- incompatible types cannot be assigned to one another. Similarly, you can't pass arguments of incompatible types to a function. This **should** fail to compile without an explicit type conversion. And if it does not, then even the first assignment has undefined behavior.

Comment: @H2CO3: I've edited my answer to focus more on _undefined behaviour_, and my answer doesn't mention implicit casts (It does mention conversion, though). And on passing incompatible types: I think I didn't say anything to contradict this in my answer (`test(&p, &f)` implies call to `test(int *, int*)`, function doesn't exist (I know, overloading is a C++ thing, but the point remains: OP is calling a function that doesn't exist)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I know, I didn't assert that your answer is wrong.

Comment: @haccks: Wasn't fishing for a vote... I've told this a few times before here: I come from a scripting background: weak/dynamic typing, undefined behaviour kept to a minimum, interpreters really _"interpreting"_ your code... the notion of undefined behaviour, is something I still have a tendency to _explain_ too much, whereas the standard simply _doesn't_ explain it

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem; Yes I remember, you told me that before. Sorry for your misunderstanding. I did't mean that.